# QGIS sub-water areas

Tags: qgis

I created one polygon shape file to sub-water areas on the river then I created 5 small area layover the first area I created, I need to cut each area to be separate area because when I move the cursor away from them they merge and become only one area that I created first.

Comment: Can you add data? Print screen etc'

Answer (score 1):

### Adding a Ring

Do I get it right, that you want to cut five areas from a large polygon?

If so:

- enter the edit mode (pencil icon [image: pencil_icon])
- activate the "Add Ring" [image: Add_Ring_icon] tool
- carve out the smaller areas:

[image: Add a Ring]